# php multilingual get two parameter

Tags: php, parameters, get, multilingual

I know how to apply the multilingual in php and i've got a problem with url.

When i click the  tag and switch the language i send one parameter right? but the point is I need one more parameter to load the page.

uhm it's kinda hard to explain.

1. There is an user list page
2. Click the one of the user and send a user_code (`<a href="userInfo.html?user_code=1">user1</a>`)
3. userInfo page is loaded by the user_code.
4. click the `<a href="?lang=en">english</a>`to switch the language on 'userInfo.html' page.
5. I need to get two parameter in same page.

how can i do it?

```
//top.php side menu
<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list animated fadeInDown" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="?lang=ko&arg1=<?= $ARG_1; ?>">Korean</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="?lang=en&arg1=<?= $ARG_1; ?>">English</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

\

```
//user list page to click the user
$user = "<tr class='even pointer'>"
    . "<td class=''><a href=\"/userInfo.html?user_code=".$row["code"]."\">"
    .$row["name"]."</a></td>"
    . "<td class=''>".$row["age"]."</td>"
    . "<td class=''>".getDataValue($USER_CATEGORY, $row["vip"])."</td>"
    . "<td class=''>".getDataValue($USER_REPU, $row["reputation"])."</td>"
    . "<td class=''>".getDataValue($USER_EMAIL, $row["email"])."</td>"
    . "<td class=''>".getDataValue($USER_GENDER, $row["gender"])."</td>"
    . "<tr>";
```

Comment: u must create your language changer urls dynamically.

Comment: Yes i want to. For example, if i load my page with url like this 'localhost/userInfo.html?user_code=1' but the problem is when i click the language button to switch. The url change dynamically like this 'localhost/userinfo.html?lang=en'. How can i change urls dynamically and flexibly like 'localhost/userinfo.html?user_code=1&lang=en"? How can i just add the rest of the url?

Comment: are you test this function. i't is helped or have problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, for generating language changer urls

```
  function getLangUrl($lang){
    $newurl="";
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url=parse_url($url);
var_dump($url);
if(isset($url["host"]))$newurl=$url["host"];
if(isset($url["path"]))$newurl.=$url["path"];
$newurl.="?lang=".$lang;
if(isset($url["query"])&&!empty($url["query"]))$newurl=$newurl."&".$url["query"];
return $newurl;

}
```

//generating url for english language

```
echo getLangUrl("en");
```

Comment: You can improve this code for yourself , i just wrote this on browser.